# sql join to get nested records

Tags: sql

Here is my table structure i want to fetch nested query
It should out as

```
first.no    second.no
1           4
2           3
```

Comment: Did you think about self join?

Comment: i don't want to repeat a combination

Comment: Add a where condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use join, and add to a where clause to make sure you'll get each pair only once (by making sure a is smaller than b- using <> will still give you 2-3 and 3-2 in the results)

```
SELECT A.no, B.no 
FROM table1 as A INNER JOIN table1 as B 
ON A.city = B.city 
WHERE A.no < B.no;
```

Answer (score 0):

A self join is needed for this case.
A query like the following will get you the result you need:

```
SELECT a.no, b.no 
FROM table_1 as a JOIN table_1 as b 
ON a.city = b.city 
WHERE a.no <> b.no;
```

Where `table_1` is the table mentioned in the question.